# Problem with datatable bound to a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-2.0, datatable

I've a datatable bound to a gridview.

The datatable has the following data:

```
JobID   Site    Job List
---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
134 A   job1    26
2241    A   job2    25
124 A   job3    26
244 B   job1    12
154 B   ads2    46
```

Am trying to take the count of distinct sites. So I write the following function:

```
    public void CreateAdmins(DataTable JobsToStart)
    {
        DataView uniqueDialers = new DataView(JobsToStart);
        uniqueDialers = uniqueDialers.ToTable(true, "Site").DefaultView;
        Debug.Print(uniqueDialers.Rows.Count);
    }
```

After executing the above function the data which is displayed in the datagridview changes. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...

Assign it to a different variable. The datagrid is looking at the same object that you are later modifying using this function.
This is because it has been 'passed by reference'. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(VS.71).aspx) article for info on that.

Comment: Show me some code plz. My assumption was you'd get an independent view if you call its constructor with a datatable...

Comment: When you say "the data which is displayed in the datagridview changes" - do you mean that the function above modifies the data grid when you don't want it to?